# Can't update or install app with new Google Account

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, data-transfer

I have two accounts on my phone

1. institutional google managed workspace - x@school.com
2. private gmail - me@gmail.com

The institution that manages (x@xchool.com) ended relationship with Google and switched to Microsoft instead. I am no longer able to use that email address as my Google Account.

I am now logged in with my private gmail - (me@gmail.com), but I can no longer update nor install existing apps linked to my obsolete account (x@school.com). I get Google Play Store error "oops something went wrong" - even if I uninstall the app and try to install it brand new.

How do I fix this?

Do I just have to remove my old gmail account (x@school.com) from the phone? If I do this, will I lose everything on my phone (i.e. all my apps will be removed?)

Comment: Removing a Google account form the device will not delete apps. Some paid app may refuse to work but they never just disappear.

Answer (score 4):

I removed my old google workspace account (x@school.com), and I am now able to install the app with my logged in (me@gmail.com).

I was just too scared to do that before. The existing apps still work, so I can now slowly uninstall/reinstall them at my leisure.